# PHP: Navigate to url with post data id (jquery and codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i have a controller with index function how need an id:

```
function index()
    {
       if ($this->input->post('id')) {
          //functions like 
          $data['donneesArticle'] = $this->ModelArticle->getArticle($this->input->post('id'));
          $this->load->view('ArticleDetail', $data, TRUE);
    }
}
```

and a list in other page of all product with :

```
<a type="button" data-id="'.$object->CodeArticle.'" class="btn btn-xs green bAfficherArticle">Show</a>
```

i get the id like this from my jquery function

```
$('.bAfficherArticle').click(function (e) {
        var yIdArticle = $(this).attr("data-id");
/* Code to navigate */
    });
```

but i can't to go detail with submit the id

**N.B: with get the function work correctly but i need to delete all the get with post**

THX

Comment: .attr("data-id"); or .data('id') instead .attr("data-idArticle")

Comment: `if (isset($this->input->post('id')))` isset will not work with input method of codeigniter so change it to `if ($this->input->post('id'))`

Comment: Are you sending id using jQuery? Please check my answer below. Need to check how your send id to your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with GET. You can pass the id with URI Segment and grab it in your controller like **$this->uri->segment()**

Add this in your jquery to Navigate:

```
 window.location.href = '<?= base_url() ?>/YOUR_CONTROLLER/YOUR_FUNCTION/'+yIdArticle;
```

and in your function do something like:

```
function index() {
    $articleId = $this->uri->segment(3); 
    //or $articleId = $this->uri->segment(4); depends on your structure

       //Do your checks here
       if (isset($articleId) && !empty($articleId)) {
          //functions like 
          //Do your functions here
    }
}
```

Comment: THX For your solution just another question, 
I do not have the risque of SQL INJECTION ?

Comment: If you use Active Record in your model, it will auto escape. Otherwise, you have to escape your data. But It is always recommended to check and filter the data you receive. Even if you use POST, there is still the possibility of Injection, if you don't follow the form validation rules. Don't mix POST/GET with SQL INJECTION,.

Answer (score 2):

I can see you are not using correct attribute name. This should be like:

**View Link**

```
<?php echo '<a type="button" data-id="'.$object->CodeArticle.'" class="btn btn-xs green bAfficherArticle">Show</a>'; ?>
```

And script would be:

```
$('.bAfficherArticle').click(function (e) {
    var yIdArticle = $(this).attr("data-id");
/* Code to navigate */
});
```

This should work

Comment: thx for your answer but my problem is how to navigate to url with post method, it work correctly with get method, but i have the risk of SQL INJECTION that's all

Comment: @marwencomunik If you aren't sanitizing your input, it doesn't matter if you're using `GET` or `POST`. Codeigniter's [query builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) escapes inputs for you, and there are no known exploits as of yet.